# Installing XBONE games is slow?

Tags: xbox-one

Why is the installation of Xbox One games so slow? (from disc)

Any games from 15GB to 50GB can take anything from a few hours to the entire night to install, why?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which game are you installing and what is your network speed?

Comment: Advances Warfare and 200Mbps

Comment: Are you on a synchronous subscriber line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to Xbox One's install system

Instead of installing the Xbox One game completely from the disc,

it installs from the disc then when it comes to a point where DLC/Update is required it will stop reading the disc to download the require DLC/Update files.

Then when they have been downloaded and fitted into the correct place/sequence of install, disc installation starts again from where the DLC/Update data left off.

This task requires constantly switching from disc installation and downloading data, instead of doing both process' at once, it does them sequentially.

To prevent this:

1. Goto settings.
2. Then network settings.
3. Then press 'A' on disconnect from your network.

Now it will install the game completely from the disc.

After this re-enable your network connection and download any updates.

This is much faster than while you are connected to the Internet.

Also another possible reason for slow installs is if your hard drive is almost full.

On most modern computers we have a defragmenter which cleans up the storage so all the blocks of data is side by side instead of spread out,

I'm unsure if the Xbox One system has an automatic defragmenter within the system but if not then,

while installing games instead of going to the next available block where data can be stored it basically rummages around the blocks just to find somewhere to store itself which takes longer

Comment: I'd be surprised if the XBOne didn't automatically defrag the drive in the background whenever there's an opportunity for it.

Comment: @MrLemon I know that's what I was thinking but they(Xbox One's) also allow for external drives so would that mean they'd be de-fragged to?

Comment: Incredibly useful information +1

Comment: Wow, that's dumb. I knew the One was downloading updates during the install process, but I never understood why my One would take so damn long compared to my PS4. I always considered MS to be superior to Sony in terms of software, but just this once I have to admit they dropped the ball. Hard.

Comment: @Foxhound, de-fragmentation is a slow process that usually does more harm then good. Typically, "on modern computers" there is no need for de-fragmentation. This is not an issue on the Xbox One.

Comment: @Eric All computers drives need defragmented haha? At one point and usualy ever so often after that, either you manually start it or the system will automatically schedule it, defragging will be around for another good while, so I have no clue what you are talking about, also please explain how defragging does more damage than good? I'm taking my Computer Science knowledge over you here unless you can back up your statement with evidence.

Comment: @Foxhound De-fragmentation tends to wear out drives if done to often. While mechanical drives suffer less due to their robustness, Modern discs based on transistor technology (SSDs etc) wear out rather quickly. De-fragmentation is typically always handles in the background and should no longer be triggered by users. You are right in that optimization is necessary but the work is done for you. That being said: do not ever schedule a de-fragmentation if your disc is almost full. It will take ages and not result in noticeable improvements. Further discussion should be taken to chat.